# text box I need to use all this methods onKeyDown, onMouseUp and onChange

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- in my text box I need to use all this methods onKeyDown, onMouseUp and onChange.
- when I try to select the text in my textbox onMouseUp event is calling,
- after selection if I delete its calling onChange method.
- is it possible to avoid, since onselection and deletion of that text I need to call another api fetchSearch
- I debugged by putting consoles but still not successful
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet below and sandbox below
- all my code is present inside Button.js which is iniside containers folder

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-moon-0h0fm

```or-tag-here
const onKeyDown = e => {
    console.log("e.keyCode", e.keyCode);

    if (e.keyCode === 8) {
      console.log("delete---->", e.target.value);
      getPosts(channel);
      if (e.target.value === "") {
        console.log("onKeyDown delete empty value--->", e.target.value);
        fetchSearch(channel);
      }
    }
  };
  const onMouseUp = e => {
    console.log("onMouseUp e.keyCode", e.keyCode);
    if (e.target.value === "") {
      console.log("onMouseUp delete empty value--->", e.target.value);
      fetchSearch(channel);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* <button
        onClick={() => {
          getPosts(channel);
          getAlert();
        }}
        className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
      >
        Get top news
      </button> */}
      <InputBase
        // className={classes.input}
        placeholder="Search Google Maps"
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Search Google Maps" }}
        onChange={e => {
          console.log("onChange e.target.value--->", e.target.value);
          getPosts(channel);
        }}
        onKeyDown={() => {
          // getPosts(channel);
          onKeyDown();
        }}
        onMouseUp={() => {
          // getPosts(channel);
          onMouseUp();
        }}

        //onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        //   onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore delete key presses in onChange method you could add the following to the first line of your onChange method:

```
if(e.target.value == '') return
```

Your onChange method would now do nothing if the text box is empty (e.g. user just pressed delete)

Similarly you could filter out the case where text is selected from the onMouseUp event e.g.:

```
if(window.getSelection().toString().length > 0) return
```

You can use similar if statements to filter out all non wanted event triggers.